# How accurate is the iPhone 3G GPS for measuring Distances between two CLLocation?

Tags: iphone, gps

In my application the user will hold the iPhone and walk in straight line, iPhone will alert the user every 2 meters to make lux measurements and record them.  Is the GPS on the iPhone accurate enough for such task? (given that the place is the runway of the airport and should have clear reception of GPS satellites signals...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't get that good a fix. 2m is about the limit of GPS and that usually requires significant time without moving. 10m seems to be what you should be able to get, though I've heard worse and (obviously Ole above) better.

Comment: 2m is the limit of GPS system I see.  hm.... I wonder if there's any way to measure distance other than GPS on the iPhone

Comment: There's nothing really reliable, but you could estimate speed at 2-5 mph depending on what exactly the user is doing and take readings every x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The best reported GPS accuracy I ever got was about 7 m. Why don't you build a simple sample app and test it for yourself? It should only take a few minutes.

Comment: Without going to the actual site (the airport) for testing, I got around +- 7m at best around my house.  However it's a cloudy day and I can see that the bluedot on the mapkitview has a circle around it indicating that it doesn't have the best accuracy yet, so I was hoping ....

But yeah, 7m seems to be what I'm getting as well.  

Thanks Ole.